# Drag imageData <img /> from Firefox to Desktop

Tags: html, firefox, drag-and-drop, html5-canvas

I would like to drag an "`imageData image`" (created with `canvas.toDataURL()`) from the browser to my Desktop.

This works on webkit (Chrome 21 and Safari 6), but **not** on Firefox 13 and 15 (I didn't check the other ones).

[You can try it here](http://jeremy.gabriele.free.fr/StackOverflow/index.html).

How can I do this?

Comment: this comment is not related your question, it's a personal advice : put an index file in the root directory of your website!

Comment: FYI [salutations are automatically removed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/181221). Don't include "hello" and "thanks" lines in your posts, they will be removed. See also ["Can I use a signature or tagline?"](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) in the FAQ.

Comment: @Avinash : Yep, I should do that. Actually this is not my website, just a page for test purposes, but you're right, I'll do that ^^.

Chris : I didn't know, questions sounds such cold this way, but ok, no "hi" and no "thanks" :).